# ToolTip Memory leak in WPF while binding a View to ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, memory-leaks, tooltip

I have an application in `WPF`, `MVVM`. Shows a list of `Images` in a `ListBox` each image is associated to different session.

My `ListBox` `ItemTemplate` looks like this,

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
      <Image 
          Source="{Binding IsClaims,Converter={StaticResource PolicyClaimsImageSelector}}" 
          ToolTipService.ShowDuration="7000">
             <Image.ToolTip>                                           
                <StackPanel>
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding WorkingSessionName}" />
                  <Views:ToolTipView DataContext="{Binding ThisViewModel}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Image.ToolTip>
      </Image>
   </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

My ViewModel

```
public class Session : BindableBase
{
    private MainViewModel _ThisViewModel;
    public MainViewModel ThisViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return _ThisViewModel;
        }
        set
        {
            _ThisViewModel = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

When ever the tool tip shows up there is a memory leak, not understanding why its happening, 
My question is that is there anything i have to do with `ToolTip` to `dispose` any memory after showing the `ToolTip` ?. if so how to do that ?

Edit

No Events are subscribed. Only binding the `DataContext` of different `ViewModels` of different `Views`

**ToolTipView.XAML**

```
 <DockPanel>
    <xcad:DockingManager  DockPanel.Dock="Left" Grid.Row="2" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
        <xcad:DockingManager.Theme>
            <xcad:MetroTheme />
        </xcad:DockingManager.Theme>
        <xcad:LayoutRoot >
            <xcad:LayoutPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                <xcad:LayoutAnchorablePaneGroup Orientation="Horizontal" DockMinWidth="150" >
                    <xcad:LayoutAnchorablePane >
                        <xcad:LayoutAnchorable Title="Folder" x:Name="ExplorerView" AutoHideWidth="300">
                            <Views:ExplorerView DataContext="{Binding ExplorerViewModel}"/>
                        </xcad:LayoutAnchorable>
                    </xcad:LayoutAnchorablePane>
                </xcad:LayoutAnchorablePaneGroup>
                <xcad:LayoutAnchorablePaneGroup Orientation="Horizontal" DockMinWidth="450" >
                    <xcad:LayoutAnchorablePane >
                        <xcad:LayoutAnchorable Title="Documents"  x:Name="TOC">
                            <Views:TableOfContentView  DataContext="{Binding TableOfContentViewModel}"/>
                        </xcad:LayoutAnchorable>
                    </xcad:LayoutAnchorablePane>
                </xcad:LayoutAnchorablePaneGroup>
                <xcad:LayoutAnchorablePaneGroup Orientation="Vertical" DockMinWidth="320">
                    <xcad:LayoutAnchorablePane DockMinHeight="400" >
                        <xcad:LayoutAnchorable Title="Properties"  x:Name="Property">
                            <Views:PropertyView DataContext="{Binding PropertyViewModel}"/>
                        </xcad:LayoutAnchorable>
                    </xcad:LayoutAnchorablePane>
                    <xcad:LayoutAnchorablePane >
                        <xcad:LayoutAnchorable Title="Search"  x:Name="Search">
                            <Views:SearchPanel DataContext="{Binding SearchViewModel}"/>
                        </xcad:LayoutAnchorable>
                    </xcad:LayoutAnchorablePane>
                </xcad:LayoutAnchorablePaneGroup>                    
            </xcad:LayoutPanel>
        </xcad:LayoutRoot>
    </xcad:DockingManager>
</DockPanel>
```

### EDIT

I have tried removing all the `Views` from the `ToolTipView.XAML` like below and show the tool tip with out any View in the `ToolTip` gives me the same `memory leak`.

Here is what now my ToolTipView.XAML looks like,

```
<UserControl x:Class="ecclient.viewer.Views.ToolTipView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:Views="clr-namespace:ecclient.viewer.Views">
</UserControl>
```

Comment: How do you establish that there is a leak? Are you positive on that?

Comment: I am debugging the application in VS2015, which has a built in tool `Diagnostic Tools` which shows the memory hike when i `MouseOver` each image, as `ToolTip` shows by that time.

Comment: @AbinMathew Raise MouseOver event 1,000,000 times and take a look, if memory consumption has grown. You don't have a memory leak probably

Comment: What are you doing inside your ToolTipView? If you are subscribing to any events of the ThisViewModel then you will leak yes. Please post the code of ToolTipView

Comment: @atomaras added the code for  view in the question. there is no events subscribed and only property's and Commands in the ViewModels.

Comment: @AbinMathew i see multiple Views created and bound to ViewModels. Since your ViewModels are statically referenced through the MainVM then if ANY of your Views attaches ANY kind of EventHandler on a ViewModel without using a WeakEventListener or unsubscribing then you will leak memory.

Comment: @atomaras to be honest there is no events in any of the `ViewModels` i have created the application for start so its clear that i dont have any `Events` i have used only command bindings.

Comment: @AbinMathew CommandBindings do wire up the CanExecuteChanged event though..That's a possible leak right there

Comment: @atomaras How to get rid of that if that is the case. ? but if i remove all `Views` from the `UserControls` as i mentioned in the edit still its getting the same memory leak. why is that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed it by creating an Interface to mimic the actual bindings. see below.

```
 public IExplorer ToolTipExplorerViewModel
    {
        get { return ExplorerViewModel; }            
    }

    public ITableOfContents ToolTipTableOFContents
    {
        get { return TableOfContentViewModel; }
    }
```

now i bind this properties with ToolTipView ie:

```
<Views:ExplorerView DataContext="{Binding ToolTipExplorerViewModel}" Grid.Column="0"/>
<Views:TableOfContentView  DataContext="{Binding ToolTipTableOFContents}" Grid.Column="1" />
```

Now Memory is not growing as we change the tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a stab in the dark, but might be something to try.    I've had an issue where certain graphics drivers would somehow trigger a leak in WPF.   We ended up WPF disabling hardware acceleration and re-testing.   It's not an ideal answer, but was enough for us to work around the problem for customers running clients for long periods of time.

In the registry (system wide)

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Avalon.Graphics]
"DisableHWAcceleration"=dword:00000001
```

Or via code for the application itself:

```
   RenderOptions.ProcessRenderMode = RenderMode.SoftwareOnly;
```

You can test what is rendered via software or hardware by using the "WPF Performance Suite" and enable the purple tint for software rendered elements.

I hope this helps.