# WPF ToolTip Memory Leak

Tags: c#, wpf, memory, memory-leaks, tooltip

Using JetBrains dotMemory, I've tracked down a memory leak in WPF's ToolTipService. This syntax has no memory leak:

```
<Button ToolTipService.ToolTip="Hello World" />
```

On the other hand, this syntax does lead to a memory leak:

```
<Button>
    <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip Content="Hello World" />
    </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
</Button>
```

For those familiar with dotMemory, here's the retention graph showing the tooltip is the only thing keeping the view model in memory.

[image]

The reason for the weird syntax, is that I'm using a HeaderedToolTip class that inherits from ToolTip. It has a Header property in addition to the ToolTip's Content, and displays the Header in bold. This memory leak has nothing to do with that control, though because as you see, this is happening with just a ToolTip as well.

I also tried defining the tooltip as a static resource, so I can do something like this:

```
<Button ToolTipService.ToolTip="{StaticResource HelloWorldToolTip}" />
```

but that also keeps it in memory.

Has anyone seen this before, or does anyone have any ideas on how else I can display a tooltip with a custom template, that doesn't lead to a memory leak? Can this:

```
<Button ToolTipService.ToolTip="Hello World" />
```

really be the only way in WPF to use a tooltip without introducing a potential memory leak?

Comment: You should contact the Microsoft WPF department with the details

Comment: I have experienced this before with a different way, check [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32764764/2470362)